# WCF error: The caller was not authenticated by the service

Tags: .net, wcf, security, wcf-binding

I am trying to access my WCF service on a server from my client console application for testing.  I am getting the following error:

> The caller was not authenticated by
>   the service

I am using `wsHttpBinding`.  I'm not sure what kind of authentication the service is expecting?

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyTrakerService.MyTrakerServiceBehavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

**Update**
It works if I change my binding to `<endpoint  "basicHttpBinding" ... />` (from wsHttpBinding)
on the IIS 7.0 hosted, windows 2008 server

Comment: Edit your post and add the relevant sections of your .config file.

Comment: How is the WCF service you are trying to consume being hosted?

Comment: If its hosted in IIS, what is the directory security set to? Anonymous or Windows Integrated?

Comment: Can you mark an answer for this question.  It looks like you were able to resolve your issue.

Comment: The action that resolved for me was change the application pool Identity from "ApplicationPoolIdentity" to "NetworkService".

Answer (score 26):

If you use basicHttpBinding, configure the endpoint security to "None" and transport clientCredintialType to "None."

```
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MyBasicHttpBinding">
            <security mode="None">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
            </security>
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior" name="MyService">
        <endpoint 
            binding="basicHttpBinding" 
            bindingConfiguration="MyBasicHttpBinding"
            name="basicEndPoint"    
            contract="IMyService" 
        />
</service>
```

Also, make sure the directory Authentication Methods in IIS to Enable Anonymous access

Comment: @KhumeshKumawat You can create and validate your own answer if you want or simply validate one of the existing (even if it is not exactly the one you chose). Your question has more than 60'000 views so it is an important one. It deserves an "official" an answer.

Answer (score 24):

I got it.

If you want to use wshttpbinding, u need to add windows credentials as below.

```
svc.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "abc";
svc.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "xxx";
```

thanks

Comment: And you may need the Domain too (.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain)

Comment: I have strange situation. From one machine i can reach service without explicit ClientCredential.Domain and from another it did not  work without Domain

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using basicHttpBinding instead of wsHttpBinding? If do not need any authentication and the Ws-* implementations are not required, you'd probably be better off with plain old basicHttpBinding. WsHttpBinding implements WS-Security for message security and authentication.

Answer (score 2):

set anonymous access in your virtual directory

write following credentials to your service

```
ADTService.ServiceClient adtService = new ADTService.ServiceClient();
adtService.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName="windowsuseraccountname";
adtService.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password="windowsuseraccountpassword";
adtService.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain="windowspcname";
```

after that you call your webservice methods.

Comment: The additional domain line was the solution to my problem, this is missing in the more credited answer below

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a self hosted site like me, the way to avoid this problem (as described above) is to stipulate on both the host and client side that the wsHttpBinding security mode = NONE.

When creating the binding, both on the client and the host, you can use this code:

```
 Dim binding as System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding 
 binding= New System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding(System.ServiceModel.SecurityMode.None)
```

or

```
 System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding binding
 binding = new System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding(System.ServiceModel.SecurityMode.None);
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the shared issue by following below steps:

1. Go to IIS-->**Sites**-->**Your Site**-->
2. Features View Pane-->**Authentication**
3. Set **Anonymous Authentication** to **Disabled**
4. Set **Windows Authentication** to **Enabled**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if needed to specify domain(which authecticates username and password that client uses) in webconfig you can put this in system.serviceModel services service  section:

```
<identity>          
<servicePrincipalName value="example.com" />
</identity>
```

and in client specify domain and username and password:

```
 client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = "example.com";
 client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "UserName ";
 client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "Password";
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused if the client is in a different domain than the server.

I encountered this when testing one of my applications from my PC(client) to my (cloud) testing server and the simplest solution i could think of was setting up a vpn.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem in `wsHtppBinding`. And I just had to add `security` mode pointing to `none`, that solved my problem and no need to switch to `basicHttpBinding`. [Check Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/271b1816-173c-4c76-a4c4-fd9fda4b5e91/how-to-disable-wcf-security?forum=wcf) and check how to disable WCF security.  Check the below config change for reference:

```
<wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="soapBinding">
        <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
            <message establishSecurityContext="false" />
        </security>
    </binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
```

Answer (score -2):

Why can't you just remove the security setting altogether for wsHttpBinding ("none" instead of "message" or "transport")?

Comment: When someone is having a problem with their security, its not very constructive to answer them with the question "why do you have to use security?"  This is a legitimate problem and assuming their application calls for a secure configuration, they need an answer, not an asinine question.

Comment: I disagree - when you're starting with any technology in this area and using sample projects, it's very easy to end up with a whole lot of security stuff enabled by default which you didn't necessarily ask for.