# How to fix "The caller was not authenticated by the service"?

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <ws2007HttpBinding>
        <binding name="UnifyDataService" maxReceivedMessageSize="1048576">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="32768" maxArrayLength="1048576" />
          <security>
            <transport>
              <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never" />
            </transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </ws2007HttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="AdoProxySite.AdoProxyBehavior"
        name="Unify.TD.Runtime.Wcf.Server.AdoProxy">
        <endpoint address="" binding="ws2007HttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="UnifyDataService"
          name="UnifyDataService" contract="Unify.TD.Runtime.Wcf.Server.IAdoProxy" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="AdoProxySite.AdoProxyBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

My WCF "Web.config" shown above, I should change "" to "". How to change it?

Comment: Provide details about your client and how / where it calls your service. Your service uses Message security with Windows client credentials so your client must be on the same network / domain as service. Your enpoint should also expose your service's identity.

Comment: My client is on the same network. I test on 2 clients, one can connect to WS, but another one cannot.

Comment: What is different about the 2 clients: e.g. are they same OS? both using domain accounts? same domain? same place in network topology (e.g. no VPN tunnel involved)?

Comment: The action that resolved for me was change the application pool Identity from "ApplicationPoolIdentity" to "NetworkService".

Answer (score 0):

This could help you: [WCF error: The caller was not authenticated by the service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284538/wcf-error-the-caller-was-not-authenticated-by-the-service)