# How to access WCF service from asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, wcf-security

We host WCF services and asp.net site on the same machine, both in IIS under `Network Service` account.

Both sites have Anonymous and Windows authentication enabled.
The service uses `WsHttpBinding`

When we call the service from `WCF Test Client` everything works fine as it sends regular domain user credentials, but when asp.net calls the service we get the exception:

> Type : System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException,
>   System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 Message : The caller was not
>   authenticated by the service.

It seems like `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` is not get authenticated, but I do not know why.

Here is config parts:

```
  <service name="Wumte.Server.Host.EDocumentsCreationNonDual">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Wumte.Server.Host.IEDocumentsCreationNonDual" bindingConfiguration="LargeMessageWsHttpBinding">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>


  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="LargeMessageWsHttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
    </binding>        
  </wsHttpBinding>
```

Comment: It's pretty hard to help you debug your issue without the WCF Service `web.config` at the minimum. Code samples may be helpful, too.

Comment: You might want to check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/284538/wcf-error-the-caller-was-not-authenticated-by-the-service

Comment: @Mark Must I provide credentials? Are credential of NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE not sent?

Comment: I think if you set the negotiateServiceCredential to false this may work:

  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WsHttpBindingConfig">
      <security>
        <message negotiateServiceCredential="false" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>